# SQL LIKE - Working on single letters only

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-like

I have an SQL LIKE query running on mySQL which runs fine on my local development server however on the production server it only works on single letters; i.e. if I enter a word any longer than one letter it returns no results.

Any ideas why and how I might be able to fix it?

Thank you in advance.

```
/**
* Searches all current vehicle listings for matches to given search string.
* @param string - Search keyword(s). Warning: If search string is empty all current vehicles are returned.
* @return array - Resulting table rows containing vin, imageFile, description, kms, auctioneerName, city, time.
*/

public function searchVehicles($search) { // 
  // Build up initial SQL query. Sub query returns all current vehicles
  $query = "SELECT * FROM (SELECT vehicles.auctionId, vin, imageFile, CONCAT_WS(' ', year, makeName, modelName) as description, kms, auctioneerName, city, time FROM vehicles, models, makes, auctions, auctioneers, locations WHERE time > NOW() AND vehicles.modelId = models.modelId AND models.makeId = makes.makeId AND vehicles.auctionId = auctions.auctionId AND auctions.auctioneerId = auctioneers.auctioneerId AND auctions.locationId = locations.locationId) AS results WHERE";
  $keywords = explode(" ", $search); // Break search into keywords

  // Loop through each keyword in the search to build up SQL query
  $firstLoop = true; // Initial loop flag
  foreach ($keywords as $keyword) {
     if (!$firstLoop) { // Check if this is not the first loop
        $query = $query . " AND"; // Then: Add extension statement to query
     } else {$firstLoop = false;} // Otherwise: Set flag to false

     // Add each keyword search to the query ensuring case insensitivity by converting to uppercase
     $query = $query . " UPPER(description) LIKE UPPER('%" . $this->escape($keyword) . "%')";
  }

  // Add ordering SQL
  $query = $query . " ORDER BY time";

  // Run query and return results (if any)
  return $this->query($query);
}
```

Comment: echo your query and run it directly in your database

Comment: I have tried something similar in phpMyAdmin and it works.

Comment: If you use a case-insensitive collation for your table data, you can forego the calls to `UPPER()`, which will allow your query to use indexes rather than a full table scan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$query = $query . " UPPER(description) LIKE '%" . strtoupper($this->escape($keyword)) . "%'";
```

Comment: I tried this. Exactly the same issue if I use UPPER(description).

Comment: If I use 'CONCAT_WS(' ', year, UPPER(makeName), UPPER(modelName))' it works fine, but all my results are uppercase which I'd like to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

Upper should be inside.

```
$query = $query . " UPPER(description) LIKE CONCAT('%',UPPER(" . $this->escape($keyword) . "),'%')";
```

Comment: SQL language by default is case insensive. You may not even need the upper, unless you configured it to be case sensitive.

Comment: With that change my development server returns no results at all.

Comment: And the production server doesn't return anything either.

Comment: My bad. Will edit the code. Upper is masked by the quotes. Did you try without upper?

Comment: No mysql server here, so couldn't test it out.

Comment: Well it works without UPPER on both development and production servers, but it is case sensitive.

Comment: I'm going to try converting to uppercase with PHP instead of SQL.

Comment: What's the collation of the table?  They're not all case-insensitive.

Comment: Hi Phoenix, the actual tables are utf8_bin and latin_swedish_ci. All text columns are set to utf8_bin.

Answer (score 0):

try using `COLLATE`

```
$query = $query . " description COLLATE utf8_general_ci like '" . $this->escape($keyword) . ")%'";
```

for case insensitive search

Comment: That works on my development server fine. The production server returns: SQL Error: COLLATION 'utf8_general_ci' is not valid for CHARACTER SET 'binary'.

Comment: Looks like your server uses binary character sets and your local machine doesn't. try `utf8_bin` instead of `utf8_general_ci`.

Comment: I'm using 'utf8_bin' on both makeName & modelName and a plain int(4) on year.

Comment: I tried that: SQL Error: COLLATION 'utf8_bin' is not valid for CHARACTER SET 'binary'.

Comment: And when I said I'm using 'utf8_bin' I meant that is what the collation is set to on the actual table column on both servers.